# Unfinished time word and Present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

I've seen in the following page I should use the present perfect in a sentence with an unfinished time word.
http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html

However in the news I often see the past simple instead, example:

> A woman died today
>
> A man was killed today.

Why is the past simple correct ? Could it be possible to say these instead?

> A woman has died today
>
> A man has been killed today.

Comment: This question may be better on [ell.se]

Comment: Someone has been teaching you things about perfect constructions that just are not true.

Comment: I have no idea why this useful question was closed. If it belongs to ELL, it would be better to move it than to close it.

Answer (score 3):

What you have learned about "unfinished time period" is incomplete.  Use present perfect if something happened during an unfinished time period, such as "today," and there is a possibility it might happen again during the same time period:

Baseball announcer:  **Smith has had two hits today**.  (The game is still on; he may bat again.)

**Smith had two hits today.**  (The game is over.)

The woman in your example is not likely to die again today, so the news report is correct.

However, if it is coverage of a hostage situation, you might say:

**One hostage has been killed (so far).**

Here there is a chance that others may be killed before the situation is over.  But if the situation has ended, the reporter would say:

**One hostage was killed.**

Comment: Agreed; well-explained. One minor point: while we almost never seen "*A man has been killed today*", we do sometimes see "*A woman has died today*". It's less common, and strikes my (American) ear as British. Perhaps it's used to soften the news or sound less vulgar?

Comment: Perhaps it's because, although that same woman cannot die again, there may still be more casualties in an ongoing situation.